# Statefulset Spark Master HA in Kubernetes If Kubernetes node running master pod itself goes down

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have deployed Spark on kubernetes with 1 master and 3 worker replicas (statefulset). I know that by virtue of K8s we get HA i.e. If Spark Master Pod goes down, K8s can restart the master pod.

In simple Spark deployment we can easily get HA with zookeeper (with primary-secondry master), But here in K8s I dont want multiple replicas of SparkMaster as with multiple replicas Spark-worker replicas are distributed among master replicas that means:
*6 workers + 2 masters => 3 workers will be associated to each Master replica.**

But I dont get HA if the kubernetes physical node running Spark Master itself goes down. As written on different sites, Statefulset pods are restarted on same node in case of failure.

Any idea how can we achieve HA with single SparkMaster (statefulset) replica in case the host/node/machine running that SparkMaster pod goes down.

---

I ran and tested it today. In case of statefulset pod, if node running that pod goes down, K8s controller/scheduler does not try to reschedule that pod on other available node rather that pod goes in *TERMINATING* state and it gets restarted when that node comes UP.

On the other hand, in case of Deployment set, a new pod gets rescheduled on an available node and the old pod still remains in *TERMINATING* state. Once the node comes up old pod that was in *TERMINATING* state gets removed.

Comment: Where is your cluster located?

Comment: @OhHiMark It is on primise.

Comment: Could you please provide your config yamls?

Comment: @OhHiMark, I am using helm chart for spark installation on K8s. Sorry cant share the configs.